# I need help to get the URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url

Sorry, I am a beginner, learning JavaScript. now I try to 
 I get the current URL in JavaScript? What is the most useful way? I have tried to do it using window.location but I think I am doing something wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: `window.location.href` will give you the full URL.

Comment: `window.location.href` will return the href of the current page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all you need in this sheet:
`window.location.href` - to get the entire URL
`window.location.host` - to get the hostname and port of the URL
`window.location.hostname` - to get the hostname of the URL
`window.location.protocol` - to get the protocol of the URL in address bar
`window.location.pathname`- to get the path and filename of the current page
`window.location.search` - to get the query portion of the URL
`window.location.hash`- to get the anchor portion of the URL
For examples, go, check out this [page](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-current-url-in-javascript.html).There are good explanations with clear examples.